# Set expiration time and other access for Azure shared access token for Azure Blob

Tags: node.js, azure

We have an application that needs to be able to upload files to Azure Blob Storage from the Browser. We are generating a Shared Access Token using the StorageSharedKeyCredential class of the azure blob sdk for JavaScript(We have a Node backend) and sending it to the frontend so that they can use it. However I am unsure if this even is the right way to do things and if so how can I specify that the token will be only valid for say 10 minutes and can only be used to Read or Write to the blob container(any one at a time).

Code :

```js
const { StorageSharedKeyCredential} = require('@azure/storage-blob')


const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential('<azure storage account name>', '<Azure Storage Account  Key>');
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your SAS token generation code.

Comment: This is not the code for generating SAS token. Where is the code for that?

Comment: That is the code we are using though. If it is wrong then could you please point me to the right resource? There are so many and I get confused.

Comment: No worries :). I answered a similar question some time ago. I have closed your question as duplicate of that. Please take a look and see if that answers your question.